# How does one convert data in API Weather - Sunrise/Sunset in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

How do I convert sunset/sunrise data into time in flutter

```
{"type":1,"id":9052,"country":"IN","sunrise":1628470082,"sunset":1628516419},"timezone":19800
```

How do I convert this data in here:  Map setrise = data['sys'];

```
Map setrise = data['sys'];
 int getsunrise = setrise['sunrise'];
  int getsunset = setrise['sunset'];

  //getting timezone
  int getTimezone = data['timezone'];
```

Where 'data' is Map of response of API

Comment: The time is in epoch time, convert it to DateTime, use [DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html). Bearing in mind the time is returned by the API is probably in seconds, not milliseconds. Also, it would be great in the future if you shared which Weather API/ library you are using.

Comment: OpenWeathermap API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(apisunsettime * 1000),
```